# What is Contact Mode Supported from EMV Tag 9F6E in EMV Contactless Book C4

Tags: emv

EMV Tag 9F6E refers to Enhanced Contactless Reader Capabilities. The description for byte 1 bit 8 is listed in the EMV doc as "Contact Mode Supported".
What does this mean?
Why is something related to contact in the contactless book?
Is this a proprietary feature related to AMEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amex **Expresspay** Tag `0x9F6E`, Byte 1 bit 8 "Contact Mode Supported" capability, when card reach the risks, allow card to continue transaction requesting to use contact Chip or reject Contactless transaction when this bit disabled.

Please look to EMVCo Contactless Specifications for Payment Systems, Book C-4, Kernel 4 used by Amex Expresspay.